# Any example of online pdf page with filename in response headers

Tags: http, http-headers

Does any one know of an existing online pdf which is served with following header ?

```
Content-Disposition: inline;filename=somename.pdf
```

Wanted to add some test scenarios for these kind of PDFs.
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following from the [Test Cases for HTTP Content-Disposition header field (RFC 6266)](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/).

- [http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/inlwithasciifilenamepdf.asis](https://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgreenbytes.de%2Ftech%2Ftc2231%2Finlwithasciifilenamepdf.asis)

[image]